# Facebook fanpage crawler

Tags: facebook, web-crawler, facebook-page

I would like to write a Facebook fanpage crawler which crawl following information 1) Fan page name 2) Fan count 3) Feeds.
I know i can use open graph API to get this, but i want to write some script which will run once in a day and get all these data and dump in my sql db.

Is there any better way to do this?

Any help is appreciable

Comment: Why not using the available API?

Answer (score 0):

I think its against the Facebook TOS, no long time ago i read some blog where the whriter create some type of spider to collect data about facebook pages user etc and he get a call from facebook lawyers