# Getting the number of facebook likes from a certain page with Nutch 2.1

Tags: facebook, apache, indexing, web-crawler, nutch

I want to ask if there is any way I can get number of times the URL was posted on public facebook pages / number of times the posted URL and comments were liked on Facebook using Nutch 2.1 crawler?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot crawl Facbook Using nutch.  https://www.facebook.com/robots.txt specifies that content inside facebook is not available for crawling.

Comment: also see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519600/facebook-fanpage-crawler?rq=1